# Can Windows Ribbon Framework be used without markup?

Tags: winapi, ribbon, win32gui

All the Ribbon framework usage examples I've met so far require a Ribbon markup to be created and complited with uicc. I wonder whether it is possible to build a Ribbon control manually by adding it and its contents in a code (C, C++, C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with Windows Ribbon Framework. To quote [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uiribbon/nf-uiribbon-iuiframework-loadui):

> To initialize the Ribbon successfully, a compiled Ribbon markup file
>   must be available as a resource. This markup file is an integral
>   component of the Ribbon framework; it specifies the controls to use
>   and their layout.

To generate the ribbon programmatically, you would have to go with a different library, like [DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2513/Controls-and-Libraries/Ribbon-Bars-and-Menu/Examples/Ribbon/How-to-Create-a-RibbonControl-in-Code) or [FluentRibbon](https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon).